# Is there a way to do nested model binding with the [FromBody] attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-binding, frombodyattribute

I'm trying to do a POST request with a JSON object as the body. The JSON object contains nested types that are predefined models in a library I am using, but when I use [FromBody] attribute only the root model gets binded while the nested models are null.

I've tried without using the [FromBody] attribute, but it also only binds the root level model.

POST Object Example:
Foo would be a model that takes a Bar object.
Bar would be a model that has properties name and firstLetter.

```
{
  "foo": [
    {
      "bar": {
        "name": "bar",
        "firstLetter": "b"
      }
    },
    {
      "bar": {
        "name": "bar1",
        "firstLetter": "b"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The Controller route looks like:

```
[HttpPost("example-route")]
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> Static([FromBody]Request request){
 //Some Action
}
```

The Request class would look like:

```
//Request class
public class Request{
  [JsonConstructor]
  public Request(Bar b){
    this.Bar = b;
  }  

  public List<Bar> Bar = { get; set; }
}

//Bar class
public class Bar {

  public Bar(string name, string firstLetter){
     this.Name = name;
     this.FirstLetter = firstLetter;
  }

  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string FirstLetter { get; set; }

}
```

When I'd call this, Bar will get assigned, but its properties of Name and FirstLetter will still be null.

Edit:I'll add the List in the example, but I may have oversimplified.The actual request looks more like:

```
{
    "prop1": "field1",
    "prop2": "4",
    "prop3": {
        "userId": "2",
        "customerId": "4",
        "type": {
            "userType": "Manager",
            "contactInfo": [
                {
                    "system": "email",
                    "value": "test@test.com"
                },
                {
                    "system": "phone",
                    "value": "555-555-5555"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Where prop1, prop2, prop3, type and contactInfo are all models defined in a library I'm using. I'm trying to get the ContactInfo object, and so far it can assigns two objects to ContactInfo when I step through, but their properties (system and value) are both null. I checked spelling and casing, but no issues there.

Answer (score 3):

Your `Request` class must match exactly what you have in the JSON, and take care ot the nestings:

```
public class Request
{
  public List<BarContainer> foo {get; set;}
  // Your constructor should initialize this list.
}

public class BarContainer
{
  public Bar bar {get; set;}
}

public class Bar
{
  [JsonProperty("name")]
  public string Name { get; set;}
  [JsonProperty("firstLetter")]
  public string FirstLetter { get; set;}
}
```

NOTE: the deserialization is case sensitive, so you need to use the exacty names in the JSON, `bar`, `foo`, `name`, `firstLetter` or use attributes or configuration to support the different casing of the property names:

- [Serialization attributes](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm)
- [JsonPropertyAttribute name](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyName.htm)

Comment: If the library I'm using doesn't have the JSON property attribute in its models, then it won't bind correct?

Comment: I suppose you're using JSON.NET (the deafult .NET serializer) and the JSON properties and the object properties names must have the same case, or use the offered alternatives.